# What permissions do tenant members have when querying guests' open extensions?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to figure out what permissions are applicable to tenant members in regards to tenant guests' open extensions in Microsoft Graph.

The [official documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#user-permissions) says permissions `User.ReadBasic.All` is available to any user by default and allows to read open extensions of all users. However, it is not clear if this is applicable to guest users as well or not.

Let's say we have a tenant `tA`, a tenant member `uA` and an external user `uB` (either member of another tenant, or a personal account). User `uB` has an open extension with some data. User `uA` adds `uB` as a guest to tenant `A` (for example, invites to a team in MS Teams). Shall user `uA` be able to read the open extension of `uB`?

I have tried this with [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). My test shows that

- If user `uB` is a business user, i.e. a member of an organizational tenant `B`, then user `uA` cannot read the extension data. `uA` can find the user, read profile, but expanding extensions returns nothing.
- If user `uB` is a personal account, e.g. some_user@outlook.com, then `uA` can read extension data.

It looks like for business accounts, user object extensions are visible only to the tenant that created the user, but not to inviting tenants. For personal accounts, however, looks like there are no restrictions, as if MS Graph user objects were created in the inviting tenant.

What are the specifications for accessing data of a guest user? Are they published anywhere?

Comment: I retagged in hopes one of the AAD folks will catch this but, FTR, it sounds like a bug to me. Your description of how the AAD account behaves is my understanding of the intended behavior: `User.ReadBasic.All` doesn't return extensions,  `User.Read.All` (or `User.Read` for reading the current user's extensions) does.  Regardless, the behavior obviously _should_ at least be the same for both AAD and MSA guests. You may want to open a support ticket with AAD directly and have them take a look.